# How to find out if a number is a hundred or thousand?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question might raise people's eyebrows but I have been googling and I don't know the keyword to search for. I just don't know the mathematical term.

What I'm trying to do is I want to round a number to the left most significant figure.

For example,

> If I have $1111$ I want to round it to $1000$
>   If I have $423$ I want to round it to $400$.

I figured out a way to do this. If somebody can confirm if I'm close to being correct, I would be very grateful.

for $423$ I would do `Math.floor(423/100) * 100` but in order to do that I would have to know for each number what to divide and multiply.

What I don't want to do is a bunch of if-else blocks like this.

```
if number is > 10 and number is < 99 then:
  divide by 100
else if number is > 99 and number is < 999 then:
  divide by 1000
// so on
```

Comment: Have you come across logarithms? They're probably the most natural solution to what you're looking for.

Comment: Just use a while loop to continually divide by ten until the number because less than 1, and count how many divisions it took.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say $n$ is your number, then

- the largest order of the power of $10$ smaller than $n$ is $\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor$ (i.e. the largest integer $d$ s.t. $10^d\leq n$
- the greatest power of $10$ smaller than $n$ is hence $10^{\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor}$
- the most significant digit is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor}}\right\rfloor$

Therefore, what you look for can be computed as
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10} n\rfloor}}\right\rfloor
\cdot
10^{\lfloor\ln_{10} n\rfloor}
$$
I would then insert an `if` statement beforehand just to rule out the case $n=0$.
A pseudocode would look like (I extended it for negative numbers using the absolute value `abs` and sign `sign` functions)

> **if** `n == 0,` **then**
>   $~~~~$**return** `0`
>   **end if**
>   `d = floor(log(abs(n)) / log(10))` $\color{green}{\%~~\text{NB: }{\tt d}\text{ is to be converted to integer type}}$
>   **return** `sign(n) * floor(abs(n)/10^d) * 10^d`

Notice that this works also for decimal numbers smaller than $1$:
e.g. for $n=0.024$ it would return $0.02$.
If this is not the wanted behaviour, edit the first `if` statement accordingly.

Comment: @snulty: thanks for your comments, I simply changed notation so that everything is well defined also for numbers smaller than $1$ (e.g. for $n=0.024$ it would return $0.02$)

Comment: You should point out in the pseudocode itself that `d` is an integer. If someone were to try this with some real type for `d`, it would produce garbage. In particular, set `d = floor(log(abs(n)) / log(10))`. And you need to return `sign(n) * floor(abs(n)/10^d) * 10^d', anyway.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree, but being no expert in programming I wouldn't know how to declare types in the pseudo code. Would you mind edit the answer yourself, please?

Comment: Since it's pseudocode, typing isn't really something you do (though if needed, you just add a comment saying "d is an integer"). But you should make the relationships explicit, instead of relying on an implicit conversion to integer as you had. In this case, that is just adding the floor function to the expression for `d`.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the number to a string and take its length to know what power of 10 to use for the rounding for one idea.

Alternatively, you could try to put the number into scientific notation and round the value that way for another option if you're OK with floating point numbers being used.

Base 10 Logarithms would also be another idea here that can work as noted in the comments.